# Exception handling in tasks in c#

Tags: c#, exception, task

I have problems with exception handling in tasks. I've found on MSDN the page to exception handling in tasks, but the example doesn't work for me...

I would expect, that the exception should be handled, but if I start the program, I get an unhandled exception error.

Thanks.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace TaskExceptionTest
   {

class Program
{
    static string[] GetAllFiles(string str)
    {
        // Should throw an AccessDenied exception on Vista. 
        return System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(str, "*.txt", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
    static void HandleExceptions()
    {
        // Assume this is a user-entered string. 
        string path = @"C:\";

        // Use this line to throw UnauthorizedAccessException, which we handle.
        Task<string[]> task1 = Task<string[]>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetAllFiles(path));

        // Use this line to throw an exception that is not handled. 
        //Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(); } ); 
        try
        {
            task1.Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {

            ae.Handle((x) =>
            {
                if (x is UnauthorizedAccessException) // This we know how to handle.
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You do not have permission to access all folders in this path.");
                    Console.WriteLine("See your network administrator or try another path.");
                    return true;
                }
                return false; // Let anything else stop the application.
            });

        }

        Console.WriteLine("task1 has completed.");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HandleExceptions();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "I get an unhandled exception error." - any chance of sharing the error?

Comment: _"an unhandled exception error"_ - which exception? At which line? Is it caught? What happens if you hit F5?

Comment: UnauthorizedAccesException was unhandled by user code at

return System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(str, "*.txt", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Comment: You don't have permission to access that directory, which is why it is getting thrown in the first place.

Comment: Yep, but it will be handled later at task.wait. It will be catched there, but I get the unhandled exception already in GetAllFiles. What should I do to not have any unhandled exception?

Comment: If you are having issues accessing a folder, that's outside the scope of this question.  Ask another question specifically for that.  My response answers your original question, external code throwing an exception is not an 'UnhandledException', just an exception and the corrected code handles it.

Comment: My issue is not accessing a folder. It was only the example on MSDN. My issue is, that I have a task and in the task I throw an exception, wich I'd like to handle (no unhandled exception in project). The question would be, how can I rewrite this project, not to have any unhandled exception error?

Answer (score 2):

Returning `false` is rethrowing the Exception.  If you just want to print the extra error information, then replace the `return false` with `return true` and get rid of the `return` in the `if` block.

```
ae.Handle((x) =>
        {
            if (x is UnauthorizedAccessException) // This we know how to handle.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You do not have permission to access all folders in this path.");
                Console.WriteLine("See your network administrator or try another path.");
            }
            return true; 
        });
```

Comment: Ok, I've corrected that part. The UnauthorizedAccesException will be handled here,  but I get the unhandled exception already in GetAllFiles. What should I do to not have any unhandled exception in my project?

Comment: you need to handle the exception at the time it is thrown, you are handling the aggregate exception from the task, which is correct the way your code is written.  If you don't want an UnauthorizedAccessException to be thrown from the task, you should handle it in the task directly.

Comment: I've tried that already. I try to throw the exception in GetAllFiles, but so I still get the unhandled exception in GetAllFiles.


`static string[] GetAllFiles(string str)
        {
            try
            {
                // Should throw an AccessDenied exception on Vista. 
                return System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(str, "*.txt", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }`